# Retornar Rows através de IPC no ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Salve meus amigos. Estou estudando um pouco sobre Electron, e me deparei com o seguinte problema na comunicação interprocessual.

Eu tenho um index.html (rendered process) que emite um evento pro main.js (main process). Este evento é uma search query na database. Consegui fazer chegar tudo direitinho, do input na index (rendered), pra query no main. Porém, agora quero retornar o resultado dessa query pra index novamente.

Abaixo, respectivamente, a função que executa a query (argQuery é o input do index.html recebido através de IPC, até aqui tudo funcionou certinho).

**MAIN.JS**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, nativeImage, ipcMain } = require("electron");

function selectSearch(argQuery) {
  connection.query(
    "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')", argQuery,
    function(err, rows, fields) {
        return rows;
    }
  );
}
```

E o eventListener que responde o rendered process, e também, executa a função acima.

**MAIN.JS**

```
ipcMain.on("query-alunos", (event, args) => {

  // args = recebido do input do index.html
  const recievedInput = args;

  //executa a function acima
  selectSearch(recievedInput, (rows, fields) => {
    // como minha ideia é fazer uma filtering list, o tamanho de rows é dinâmico
    // pesquisar E => retorna 200 alunos, pesquisar Julio, retorna 50, etc
    rows.forEach(element => {
      console.log("Sending to Rendered ->" + element.nome);
      //em tese deveria mandar pro rendered os nomes retornados.
      event.sender.send("fetch-alunos", element.nome)
    });
  });
});
```

e então, no index (rendered), eu teria mais um listener pra ouvir este "fetch-alunos" e fazer algo com os nomes retornados.

Esta foi lógica que veio na minha cabeça de primeira, mas está retornando undefined. Caso alguém consiga me explicar, fico grato!

Caso alguém precise do code do rendered

**INDEX.HTML**

```
         const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

         function sendToMain(processName, toSend){
               ipcRenderer.send(processName, toSend);
                //...code irrelevante pra pergunta que cortei
            }

          // final listener que pega o resultado da query e faz algo
          ipcRenderer.on("fetch-alunos", (event, args) => {
               alert("Querys Chagam ao Rendered caso tudo esteja OK");
            }
          );
            
         //envia o value do input para cada letra digitada no input
         function searchAluno(){
            if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
                  const nomeAluno = document.getElementById("inputTodo").value;
                  sendToMain("query-alunos", nomeAluno);
            } else { 
               console.log("Invalid Event")
            }

         }
```

Comment: Por que você não retorna `event.sender.send` uma única vez, enviando a lista, ao invés de enviar N vezes, enviando um nome por vez? E o `alert` no renderer tá sendo exibido, só que `args` está `undefined`, é isso?

Comment: Eu tentei já, 

main.js (simplificado)
`ipcMain.on("query-alunos", (event, args) => {connection.query("SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE nome LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')", args, (rows, fields) => {event.sender.send("fetch-alunos", rows)});});`

No caso o Alert dispara, mas passando as rows como args, no rendered ela retorna null.

index.html (rendered)
`ipcRenderer.on("fetch-alunos", (event, args) => {console.log("Aqui eram pra voltar as querys finais mas retorna null "+args);});`